# Display pdf from the weburl iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, pdf, sdk, thumbnails, pdf-viewer

I am working on one project I want to display the pdf which is on the website, I have the url of the pdf any idea how I can do it.
Also I want to create a thumbnail of the pdf which is on the website.

Answer (score 2):

you could display a pdf in your device.

Passing the url to UIWebView directly.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 420)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```