# How to fetch pdf file in Controller file in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have to read pdf file from my controller. How to load it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UIWebView` to view the `pdf` file.

Check the below SO post.

[Display pdf from the weburl iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457329/display-pdf-from-the-weburl-iphone-sdk/5457400#5457400)

Tutorial [link1](http://How%20to%20display%20a%20remote%20PDF%20file%20in%20iOS%20UIWebView?)

From apple

[Using UIWebView to display select document types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html)

Comment: @Jhaliya.How to give scroll view for scrolling pdf files. Thanks great update.

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar   : `UIWebView` will take care of that because it's inherited from `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I wrote code for fetching pdf file. I added that pdf in my resource directory of project.
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Chapter01Page01.pdf"];

Comment: Is it write ? I am not seeing pdf file is appearing on screen.

Comment: Use a UIDocumentInteractionController instead for the default pinch zoom and scrolling behaviour that iOS uses by default for documents etc.

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar : Have you added **webview** object as **subview** in your main view ?

Comment: @Jhaliya. I have written 
 [self.view addSubview:webView];
 [webView release];  And i also added one webview in view from builder. And also why this is not reading my local file which is kept in resiurce directory.

Comment: This is loading pdf file, if i am giving URL pat as per above link. But scroll is not vertical scroll is not coming. I am seeing horizantal scroll. And also kindly know me how to read local file, which is kept in my project->resource->directory.

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar  : i think you have'nt given the correct file path.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can read and store  your pdf locally:

First create UIWebView and include <<**UIWebViewDelegate**>>

```
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourPDF.pdf"]; 
 if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
           // download file , here "https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf" = pdf downloading link
         NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf"]];
            //Store the downloaded file  in documents directory as a NSData format
         [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [yourWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [yourWebView setDelegate:self];
     yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
     [yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Or, if you simply want to read/load pdf from your Resource folder then simply do this :

```
     NSString*  filePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"pdf"]];
    /// or you can even read docs file as : pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"docx"]
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [yourWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [yourWebView setDelegate:self];
     yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
     [yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```